# Realizar una resta entre dos fechas y que me devuelva la cantidad de meses en R

Tags: r

disculpen la insistencia, pero sigo con problemas con el procesamiento que me encuentro realizando y ha sido de mucha ayuda sus consejos.

Tengo una variable `SALUD$CONTROLRECOD` que muestra las fechas del último control de salud de las personas.
Lo que necesito hacer es saber cuantos meses han pasado desde el último control de salud hasta mi fecha de análisis, que es el 31/12/2020.

Cuando hago la diferencia entre estas dos fechas me hace el cálculo en días, y no logro encontrar como hacerlo en meses.
Probé realizando la división entre 30 (aunque lo correcto sería 30,4 días por mes -lo hice así porque no me tomaba el 30,4 como objeto) y luego hice el redondeo con trunc que me pareció me iba a dar el resultado más parecido al excel, pero quiero saber si hay alguna forma más directa de hacerlo.

```
#32.CALCULAMOS LOS MESES QUE HAN TRANSCURRIDO DESDE EL ULTIMO CONTROL MEDICO

fechacorrida<-as.Date(31/12/2020,format="%d/%m/%A") 
cantidaddiasmeses<-as.numeric("30")

SALUD$MESESDESDECONTROL<-(fechacorrida - SALUD$CONTROLRECOD)/cantidaddiasmeses

SALUD$MESESDESDECONTROL<-trunc(SALUD$MESESDESDECONTROL)

SALUD$MESESDESDECONTROL<-as.numeric(SALUD$MESESDESDECONTROL)
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

### Paquete

En `R` existe un paquete llamado `lubridate` que contiene una función `interval` para obtener la diferencia entre fecha por días, horas, semanas o `meses` como es este caso (aunque hay una diferencia a considerar que explicaré al final con otro método)

```
installed.packages(lubridate) # si no lo tienes instalado
```

### Dataframe

Se tiene el siguiente dataframe (se llama también el paquete `lubridate`):

```
library(lubridate)

# dummy data
salud <- read.table(header = TRUE,
    text = 'MesesDeControl
            01/04/2020
            23/06/2020
            17/08/2020
            27/10/2020
')

# Dar formato a la columna MesesDeControl con tryFormats
salud$MesesDeControl <- as.Date( salud$MesesDeControl, tryFormats=c("%d/%m/%Y") )
```

Estas Meses de control deben por lo que entiendo ser comparados con una "fecha corrida" para obtener los meses.
Para ello hay que fijar dicha fecha y repetirla de acuerdo a la cantidad de datos contenidos en la columna `MesesDeControl` con el fin de obtener las diferencias de interés

```
# Se asigna la fecha '31/12/2020' a la variable 'fecha_corrida'
fecha_corrida <- as.Date('31/12/2020', tryFormats=c("%d/%m/%Y"))

# Se asigna la variable 'fecha_corrida' a la columna 
# 'FechaCorrida' del dataframe 'salud'
salud$FechaCorrida <- rep(fecha_corrida, length(salud))

salud
#  MesesDeControl FechaCorrida
#     2020-04-01   2020-12-31
#     2020-06-23   2020-12-31
#     2020-08-17   2020-12-31
#     2020-10-27   2020-12-31
```

### Respuesta

Con los datos organizados se obtiene los meses respectivos:

```
# Se usa la función 'interval' del paquete 'lubridate' para espaciados de un mes
# Si usas months(3) puede ser trimestres por ejemplo
salud$Meses <- interval(salud$MesesDeControl,  salud$FechaCorrida) %/% months(1)

salud
#  MesesDeControl FechaCorrida Meses
#     2020-04-01   2020-12-31     8
#     2020-06-23   2020-12-31     6
#     2020-08-17   2020-12-31     4
#     2020-10-27   2020-12-31     2
```

### Consideraciones Finales

Aunque a mi parecer, la pregunta del OP no va por esta línea, veo oportuno hacer la siguiente acotación.

Hay que tener en cuenta cómo se define la diferencia de tiempo. Por ejemplo tomemos

```
#  MesesDeControl FechaCorrida Meses
#     2020-04-01   2020-12-31     8
```

En estricto el día empieza a las 0:00 horas y termina a las 11:59:59, es decir, para el caso anterior `debería ser 9 meses y no 8`. (aunque esto dependerá del análisis a efectuar)

Existe un paquete `sqldf` que en su versión simplificada trabaja con `SQLite` (puede trabajar también con `MySQL` o `PostgresSQL`)

Si empleamos el código expuesto lineas más arriba excepto la función `interval` se tiene lo siguiente:

```
# installed.packages(sqldf)
library(sqldf)

df <- sqldf("
        SELECT
            *,
            strftime('%m',FechaCorrida) - strftime('%m',MesesDeControl) AS MesesSQL
        FROM salud"
)

df
#  MesesDeControl FechaCorrida MesesSQL
#     2020-04-01   2020-12-31        9  # Aquí se obtiene 9 meses y no 8
#     2020-06-23   2020-12-31        6
#     2020-08-17   2020-12-31        4
#     2020-10-27   2020-12-31        2
```

> *Nota:* La estructura de SQL usa una función `strftime` la cual acota la fecha de control y corrida a mes `%m` para que se calcule la diferencia y así obtener los meses en cuestión. El `*` sólo indica tráeme todas las columnas contenidas en el dataframe 'salud' (tabla para SQL)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó de maravillas